# Python equivalent of R's R2HTML to output interactive results?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I did some analysis in python that I'd like to output to something not terribly ugly in HTML, preferably without getting a full-fledged templating engine involved or making many design decisions about output.  This is simple stuff like:

```
>>> pprint(myobject)
{u'dogs': 10,
 u'cats': 190}
>>> df.state.value_counts()
MI    200
CA    100
NY     90
TX     21
```

In R, I would use...

```
HTMLStart(outdir=".",file= "filename", extension="html",echo=FALSE, HTMLframe=TRUE)
summary(myobject)
describe(df$state)
HTMLStop()
```

And I would get a beautiful set of html pages formatted into tables.  Is there anything similar for the interactive python data analyst who just wants some easy HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataFrame object has a `to_html()` method that will output the code for an HTML table of your data.

Check out Wes McKinney's post about it [here](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=356).

Comment: That is pretty slick.  Thank you.